# Parity RPC Port Redirecting to UI Interface

Tags: json-rpc, parity, gui

It seems that whenever I run Parity and I bring up :8545 in a web browser (locally or on the public net), it redirects to :8180 OR simply gives me an error.  In this case, I get the Parity UI styling saying:

```
404 Not Found
Your homepage is not available when Trusted Signer is disabled.

You can still access dapps by writing a correct address, though. Re-enable Signer to get your homepage back.
```

What I am expecting is the "normal" weird error I would get if I ran geth and looked at port 8545 in a browser.  Text gobbledegook that I could re-create and post if you need the details.

But what I really want to be able to do is execute commands via the RPC interface across the public internet.  Is there another, better way that I should be going about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to access an HTTP RPC port via a browser and thus Parity forwards you to the Wallet UI.

If you want to access RPC via HTTP, you can use curl or similar.

```
curl --data '{"method":"web3_clientVersion","params":[],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8545
```

If you want to use the RPC API via your JavaScript console, you can open the Parity Wallet, navigate to the Applications tab and open the Parity Console dapp.

[image: screenshot]

```
> web3.version.node
< "Parity//v1.7.0-unstable-18c3e90db-20170523/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.17.0"
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: It does, and I knew not to access the RPC via browser.  But since I was trained to expect one behavior from geth, Parity's behavior was confusing me.  Might I suggest a redirect message that say "you are trying to access the RPC port via browser.  Redirecting to the Parity UI console DAPP."  Or something?  That way I don't worry that I've got my reverse proxies misdirected.