# JSON RPC calls using Parity. Difference between Infura and Geth?

Tags: web3js, parity, json-rpc, infura

I began by trying to follow the article on [front running bancor with Python.](https://hackernoon.com/front-running-bancor-in-150-lines-of-python-with-ethereum-api-d5e2bfd0d798)  I thought it would be easy to send an api request to my full   node then replicate the same request in Python--all following the tutorial.  The only difference was that the author used Geth and I am running Parity.  The inability to figure out how to use JSON RPC has led me down a rabbit hole.  I don't really know (1) what I'm doing wrong or (2) if I even conceptually understand JSON RPC at this point.

## The problem:

I should be able to run this curl command: `curl -X POST --data \
    '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getTransactionByHash", \
    "params":["0x314e0246cfc55bc0882cbf165145c168834e99924e3ff7619ebd8290e713386d"], \
    "id":123}' localhost:8545`

## And get a result like this:

`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":123, "result":{
"blockHash":"0x42ea1578c23b159186853961dfbdfcdec6b40d23d8f1d971827412bc6948386b",
"blockNumber":"0x3dfb88",
"From":"0xcaf82fcb3a0323566c0f306684376e3e66d6284b",
"To":"0x77a77eca75445841875ebb67a33d0a97dc34d924",
"gasPrice":"0xba43b7400",
"hash":"0x314e0246cfc55bc0882cbf165145c168834e99924e3ff7619ebd8290e713386d",
"value":"0x6c6b935b8bbd400000",
...}}`

## Howevever when I run it with localnode connected to parity I only get:

```
Supplied content type is not allowed. Content-Type: application/json is required
```

I found the Parity JSON-RPC API documentation and realized the formatting is different.
[image]

So I reformatted the curl command to look like this:

```
curl --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getTransactionByHash",
"params":["0x314e0246cfc55bc0882cbf165145c168834e99924e3ff7619ebd8290e713386d"], "id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8545
```

I solved the Content Type error but then got a null result:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":null,"id":1}
```

Then looking at this stack exchange [article](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16530/parity-rpc-port-redirecting-to-ui-interface/16552#16552) I realized that Parity has it's own Web3 console.  So, I thought maybe I don't have to use curl at all, and can just run.

```
web3.eth.getTransaction('0x314e0246cfc55bc0882cbf165145c168834e99924e3ff7619ebd8290e713386d')
```

[image]

and I still get null return.

As a side note I have also tried to do the call using Infura's [api](http://docs.infura.apiary.io/#reference/0/v1jsonrpcnetworkmethods/get)

```
curl --include \
 --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
 --header "Accept: application/json" \
```

'https://api.infura.io/v1/jsonrpc/mainet/getTransaction?params=0x314e0246cfc55bc0882cbf165145c168834e99924e3ff7619ebd8290e713386d'

[image: Infura]
But am getting 404 return.

I really want to understand what I am doing wrong but I don't know where exactly to find the resources to teach myself, and feel a little stuck.  Thanks in advance for anything that can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you running this on Windows? I'v tried with infura.io and this works  `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getTransactionByHash","params":["0x314e0246cfc55bc0882cbf165145c168834e99924e3ff7619ebd8290e713386d"],"id":123}' https://mainnet.infura.io/<token>`

Comment: No, Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

Call it like this

```
curl --data '{"method":"web3_clientVersion","params":[],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-X POST localhost:8545
```

It need

```
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Answer (score 0):

The call you provided seems proper, and it works on my local parity - you might've had blockchain not completely synced up.

Comment: Would you be willing to show me exactly how you entered it?  My node is definitely fully synced

Comment: I literally copied your call, and ran it from terminal on an Ubuntu server running parity:  :~$ curl --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getTransactionByHash", "params":["0x314e0246cfc55bc0882cbf165145c168834e99924e3ff7619ebd8290e713386d"], "id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8545
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"blockHash":"0x42ea1578c23b159186853961dfbdfcdec6b40d23d8f1d971827412bc6948386b","blockNumber":"0x3dfb88","chainId":"0x1"...

Comment: (also, why the downvotes? :O )